# Creating SQL string in VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, pass-through

I'm trying to put SQL from a pass-through query into a VBA module since the query is giving me problems.  I'm encountering an issue in it, however.  Here's the error message I get:

[image]

Here's the section of code that generates the error

```
Sub Passthrough()

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "select spriden_id AS 'UIN', spriden_first_name AS 'First', spriden_last_name AS 'Last', SPBPERS_SSN AS 'SSN', pebempl_ecls_code," & _
"pebempl_term_date, pebempl_last_work_date, ftvvend_term_date," & _
"Case When sfrstcr_pidm is not null Then 'A'" & _
"When sfrstcr_pidm <> ' '" & _
"Then 'A' Else Null End AS 'StudentStatus'," & _
"spbpers_citz_code AS 'Citizenship',Null AS 'Current Student/Employee (Y/N)',  Null 'TIN Match (Y/N)'" & _

......

  DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

End Sub
```

Comment: check the value of strSQL before you run it so you can see if the final query is valid or not

Comment: Why are you not saving query as stored object instead of VBA string especially since you do not concatenate any VBA values into string? Also, `RunSQL` is reserved for action queries, not `SELECT` queries.

Answer (score 5):

This is a spacing issue with the evaluated string. You can see in the error message that it is trying to run the sql "`... Then 'A'When sfrstcr_pidm <> ' 'Then 'A'...` where there are not spaces between the 'A' and next `When` statement or the ' ' and the next `Then` statement Just add a space to the end of the string where you are splitting it onto new lines.

```
Sub Passthrough()

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "select spriden_id AS 'UIN', spriden_first_name AS 'First', spriden_last_name AS 'Last', SPBPERS_SSN AS 'SSN', pebempl_ecls_code, " & _
"pebempl_term_date, pebempl_last_work_date, ftvvend_term_date, " & _
"Case When sfrstcr_pidm is not null Then 'A' " & _
"When sfrstcr_pidm <> ' ' " & _
"Then 'A' Else Null End AS 'StudentStatus', " & _
"spbpers_citz_code AS 'Citizenship',Null AS 'Current Student/Employee (Y/N)',  Null 'TIN Match (Y/N)' " & _

......


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Go back to your query object as you need a *connection* specified.

*RunSQL* is for local queries only.